# Properties of weak derivatives: Let $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$. Then, prove that $D^{\alpha}u \in W^{k-|\alpha|,p}.$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Properties of weak derivatives: Let $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$. Then, prove that $D^{\alpha}u \in W^{k-|\alpha|,p}.$

My attempt:- We know that $D^\alpha u$ exists in the weak sense and $D^\alpha u \in L^p(U), \forall |\alpha|\leq k.$ ($\because$ By definition)
In order $D^\alpha \in W^{k-|\alpha|,p}, $  $D^{\beta}D^{\alpha}u$ must exists for $|\beta|\leq k-|\alpha|.$
For the existence,
Consider the integral $\phi\in C_c^\infty (U)$
$$\int_U D^\alpha u D^\beta \phi dx=(-1)^{|\alpha |}\int_U D^\alpha D^\beta u  \phi dx$$
$$ =(-1)^{|\alpha |}\int_U D^{\alpha +\beta} u  \phi dx=\frac{1}{(-1)^{|\alpha+\beta|}}(-1)^{|\alpha |}\int_U u D^{\alpha+\beta}\phi dx.  $$  I know it is valid for $|\alpha+\beta|\leq k \implies |\beta+\alpha -\alpha|\leq |\alpha+\beta|+|\alpha|\leq k+|\alpha|.$
I don't know how to show $|\beta|\leq k-|\alpha|.$ Could you help me?

Comment: For multi-indexes $\alpha,\beta$ we have $|\alpha+\beta| = |\alpha|+|\beta|$.

Comment: Thank you. Now let me try in that way.